# Selenium misses random elements on "Follow" button from a Instagram user followers list

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, instagram, selenium3

Trying to select the "Follow" buttons from a Instagram user followers list like this one:

[Instagram followers list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGwZe.png)

I'm using this function to get the buttons. That weird string is the class that instagram uses for the buttons, and `ChromeUtils.findByXpaths()` is just a shortcut to `driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath));`

```
private static List<WebElement> getFButtons(){
    return ChromeUtils.findByXpaths("//button[@class=\"sqdOP  L3NKy   y3zKF     \"]");
}
```

It works fine for on the first user but when it clicks one of the last one, Instagram loads more users on the list, and then Selenium starts missing a lot of "Seguir" buttons, even if they have exactly the same class, `sqdOP  L3NKy   y3zKF`

[Example of missed buttons and their class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Il7kc.png)

Then if scrolled manually to load more users, it starts working again only with some buttons, it looks like that it follows a random pattern. I also tried selecting the buttons by its text, "Seguir" but no success.
This is the code that interacts with the buttons:

```
int i = 0;
int max = r.getMaxFollowPSession();
List<WebElement> fButtons = getFButtons();
while (i < max) {
    try {
        // This if checks if it selected the follow button from the main page, I added a sout to check if
        // this was the problem but it isn't
        if (fButtons.get(i).getAttribute("class").equals(CLASS_BIG_FOLLOW_BUTTON)) {
            i++;
            max++;
            System.out.println("Mistake with follow page button, selectiong next button");
            continue;
        }
        fButtons.get(i).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        i++;
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        fButtons = getFButtons();  // Once the list of selected buttons end, it selects the new ones.
    }
}
```

Am I missing something or is this a Selenium bug?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Try again increasing sleep to 10 sec : Thread.sleep(10000). If no improvement, inform again please.

Comment: I tried it but this doesn't seem to fix it. I ended up getting the list <li> childrens using `WebElement li = list.findElement(By.xpath("./li[" + index + "]")); ` and then getting the follow button from there

Comment: Try again using findElements - first insert all follow elements and then follow your desired element by index.